# onActivityResult for Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS) called immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity, onactivityresult

In my splash screen I have request to server, but when there's no internet connection i'm opening

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(settingsIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_CONNECTION);
```

But problem is that `onActivityResult` is called immediately  with requestCode = `REQUEST_ENABLE_CONNECTION`

I've also tried to add the flag `FLAG_NEW_TASK` for the intent with no luck.

The activity is **not** `singleTop` or `singleInstance` in the `manifest`.

What is the best android solution to resolve this issue? I don't want to use Broadcast as it's not the best way to my flow so it will be taken as last choice for me.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What result code do you get in onActivityResult? RESULT_CANCELLED or anything else?

Comment: RESULT_CANCELED but it doesn't really matter because onActivityResult is called, and when returning to the app with back button it doesn't called any more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `onActivityForResult` isn't working well for you (as @CommonsWare suggested, it's fine)  you can create a simple flow that should work fine:

In your activity, add

```
private boolean isReturnedFromSettings = false;
```

When you decide there's no internet connection and want to open the settings activity, use `startActivity` and set `isReturnedFromSettings = true;`

In your Activity's onResume, add this:

```
if (isReturnedFromSettings) {
isReturnedFromSettings = false;

//DO WHATEVER
}
```

Should work...

Comment: This flag would need to be maintained in `onSaveInstanceState` & `onRestoreInstanceState` because you can lose it if system kills your `Activity` when the Settings screen is open.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the best android solution to resolve this issue?

There is no issue. The activities of the settings app are not documented to support `startActivityForResult()`, and the main activity (`Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS`) does not offer it at all.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your intent:

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: in my intent

```
activity.startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_SYSTEM_WRITE_PERMISSION);
testDelaydRingtoneSetting(mUri, mCallback);
```

and here the trick:

```
private void testDelaydRingtoneSetting(Uri mUri, KrollFunction mCallback) {
        final Uri ringtoneUri = mUri;
        final KrollFunction callback = mCallback;
        final Context context = TiApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (Settings.System.canWrite(context)) {
                Activity activity = TiApplication.getInstance()
                        .getCurrentActivity();
                activity.finishActivity(REQUEST_SYSTEM_WRITE_PERMISSION);
                setRingtone(ringtoneUri, callback);
            } else
                testDelaydRingtoneSetting(ringtoneUri, callback);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this.

`Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(settingsIntent);`

Comment: I need to return to my activity in a proper way to ask if device has connection, this is not good for me at all.

Comment: wt does it mean? ...please explain why you not do this. you can check the (device has connection)  in the onResume method of the Activity.