# Proper way to handle ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS activity

Tags: android

I want write settings permission in order to start portable WLAN hotspot...

this is what i got,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext())) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
            }
        }
```

this works fine until i press back button after i grant permission.

after pressing back button resultCode is 0 always, therefore further code is not working properly.

Comment: possible work around is to check on result if the wifi state is changed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065592/how-to-detect-wifi-tethering-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after pressing back button resultCode is 0 always

An `ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS` is not documented to return a result. Most activities do not return a result.

Do not call `startActivityForResult()` — just use `startActivity()`. When needed, call `Settings.System.canWrite(this)` to see if you have permission.

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer. Usually, we use Settings. ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS just after checking the result of canWrite(), after attempting to do a prohibited operation. Therefore, in terms of UX the best way to do it would be to continue the operation - now allowed - just after the user comes back from the settings activity. That's why it's a good idea to use startActivityFromResult() and look at the request code (ignoring the result code)

Answer (score 3):

> An ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS is not documented to return a result. Most activities do not return a result.

Maybe it's not documented, but as you noticed yourself there is always a result for `ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS`. While the `resultCode` is always 0, the result does hand you back your original `requestCode`.

So you can use this to check in `onActivityResult` whether you now have the permission that you asked for.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_SYSTEM:
                boolean canWrite = Settings.System.canWrite(this);
                // Handle the result here
                break;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Good idea but "onActivityResult" calling when "ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS" open.

Comment: I found the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41681837/7841581